# Como redirecionar de uma página a outra em Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Gostaria de dizer que sou extremamente leigo em PHP e Laravel, mas estou tentando aprender para um trabalho.
Já fiz um CRUD básico antes com a ferramenta mas tenho uma dúvida em um projeto atual.

Eu criei uma aplicação em Laravel, meu objetivo é que um paciente se cadastre mas antes passe por uma tela inicial. Na pasta 'views/layouts', mudei o 'welcome.blade.php' para minha necessidade, nela, criei um menu com a tag ul. Essa seria a tela inicial. Também criei um outro arquivo chamado 'cadastro.blade.php', que seria a tela de cadastro.
Ao clicar em um link, que fica nesse menu da 'welcome.blade.php' (a tag **a**), eu gostaria que o usuário fosse direcionado a página 'cadastro.blade.php'.
Eu sei que em 'routes/web.php', há os caminhos das rotas, mas não sei muito bem como fazer isso se encaixar. Por exemplo, eu gostaria que ao acessar a rota '/cadastro', eu fosse capaz de ir a página 'cadastro.blade.php'. Porém, quando tento isso, apenas aparece 'Not found'.
Me desculpem os erros, como eu disse, não sei muito bem como funciona.

Meu código em 'welcome.blade.php' (apenas um link simples):

```
    <label class="nome"> CADASTRO </label>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <hr>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="titulo"> Pré-cadastro de paciente </span>
    </a> 
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Meu código em 'routes/web.app':

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/pre-cadastro', 'PacientesController@create');
```

Meu 'PacientesController':

```
class PacientesController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
        return view('cadastro');
    }
}
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, bem vindo ao SO.
Recomendo ler sobre [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) (rotas nomeadas em pt-BR)
e sobre o helper [route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route). Feito isso vamos lá

Não existe rota para /cadastro e sim para /pre-cadastro, por isso o **Not found 404**.

Se você deseja que ao acessar /cadastro você "fosse capaz de ir a página 'cadastro.blade.php'" então altere (em web.php):

```
Route::get('/pre-cadastro', 'PacientesController@create');
```

para

```
//nao entrarei em detalhes de boas práticas
Route::get('/cadastro', 'PacientesController@create')->name('nomeDaSuaRotaUnica');
```

E para que, ao clicar no link, você seja "redirecionado" para PacientesController > create e a view "cadastro.blade.php" seja renderizada (repare na parte **{{route('nomeDaSuaRotaUnica')}}**):

```
<label class="nome"> CADASTRO </label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <hr>
      <a href="{{route('nomeDaSuaRotaUnica')}}">
        <span class="titulo"> Pré-cadastro de paciente </span>
      </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Edit. Assumi que esteja utilizado o laravel 8.x mas o exemplo funciona ao menos nas versões > 6.x

Answer (score -1):

Seguindo o exemplo anterior voce pode colocar tambem o caminha direto.

```
  <a href="/cadastro">
    <span class="titulo"> Pré-cadastro de paciente </span>
  </a>
```

Answer (score -2):

De acordo com vendor.laravel.framework.src.Illuminate.Foundation.Application.php

linha 41 - a versão do meu Laravel é 9.30.1

e o código acima não funcionou, mudei assim:

### routes.web.php

```html
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PacientesController;
Route::get('/', function () {return view('welcome');});
Route::get('cadastro', [PacientesController::class,'create']);
```